# boost::mpl transform operation meta-function argument error

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

In the [Boost MPL web-documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/implementing.html), it talks about passing meta-function classes as arguments to boost::mpl::transform.  The meta-function argument, in this case, should be an operation of some sort to carry out on an mpl::ForwardSequence.  However, when applying mpl::transform to an mpl::map using a simple meta-function class, I am getting template errors. (As these errors are quite extensive, I have included only what I believe to be the relevent bit.  I am more than happy to post a more extensive error report if requested.)

Error:

```
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/bind.hpp:207:21: error: no type named     ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<boost::mpl::push_front<mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::mpl::map0<>, boost::mpl::pair<unsigned int, INT32U> >’
test_boost_mpl.cpp:106:1: error: ‘from_native_tmap’ was not declared in this scope
```

In my particular case my code looks like the following:

```
/* stl includes */
#include <cstdint>

/* boost includes */
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/empty.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>

struct Boolean {
  enum { tag_value = 0x83 };
};

struct INT32U {
  enum { tag_value = 0x84 };
};

typedef mpl::map
< 
  mpl::pair<Boolean, bool>,
  mpl::pair<INT32U, std::uint32_t>
> to_native_tmap;

struct swap_f {
  template<typename PAIR>
  struct apply {
    typedef typename mpl::pair<typename PAIR::second, typename PAIR::first> type;
  };
};

typedef mpl::transform<to_native_tmap, swap_f>::type from_native_tmap;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( is_same
                   <mpl::at<from_native_tmap, bool>::type, Boolean> ));
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( is_same
                   <mpl::at<from_native_tmap, std::uint32_t>::type, INT32U> ));

int main(void) { return 0; }
```

My intent is have a mapping to native c++ types in `to_native_tmap` and then the reverse mapping in `from_native_tmap`.

This code fails on either `BOOST_MPL_ASSERT()` or if I attempt to instantiate the `to_native_tmap` mpl::map type.

A big 'Thank You!' up front to anyone willing to help.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow! please give a minimal [self contained](http://sscce.org/) example that reproduces your problem (in this case showing your native_to_goose_tmap)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  I apologize for not doing this initially.  I am new to both Stack Overflow and Template-Metaprogramming, so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: no apologies required, but makes sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/* stl includes */
#include <cstdint>

/* boost includes */
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/empty.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/inserter.hpp> //ADDED
#include <boost/mpl/insert.hpp> //ADDED

namespace mpl= boost::mpl; //ADDED
using boost::is_same; //ADDED

struct Boolean {
  enum { tag_value = 0x83 };
};

struct INT32U {
  enum { tag_value = 0x84 };
};

typedef mpl::map
< 
  mpl::pair<Boolean, bool>,
  mpl::pair<INT32U, std::uint32_t>
> to_native_tmap;

struct swap_f {
  template<typename PAIR>
  struct apply {
    typedef typename mpl::pair<typename PAIR::second, typename PAIR::first> type;
  };
};

//The default inserter used by mpl::transform requires that the container have a push_front algorithm
//This isn't the case for mpl::map (as the assertion in g++4.8.0 reveals: REQUESTED_PUSH_FRONT_SPECIALIZATION_FOR_SEQUENCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
//In this case you need to add a custom inserter
typedef mpl::inserter<mpl::map0<>, mpl::insert<mpl::_1,mpl::_2> > map_inserter; //ADDED
typedef mpl::transform<to_native_tmap, swap_f, map_inserter >::type from_native_tmap; //CHANGED

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( is_same
                   <mpl::at<from_native_tmap, bool>::type, Boolean> ));
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( is_same
                   <mpl::at<from_native_tmap, std::uint32_t>::type, INT32U> ));

int main(void) { return 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I will run the code and up-vote/accept as soon I get back from lunch.

Comment: @maaronking the code compiles and runs correctly on gcc 4.7.2, and probably on much earlier versions as well (because Boost.MPL hasn't really changed since ages)

Comment: @user2241635 you should really get a named SO account, because if you can answer these Boost.MPL questions so easily, then you can really help out here!

Comment: @user2241635 rhalbersma is correct on both accounts.  Your solution works perfectly and you should get a named account.  I have been banging my head on this problem for a couple of days now.  Thank you for taking the time to provide the working solution.

Comment: I would up vote the answer but I dont have enough 'reputation'.  Sorry.  I did select it as the working solution.